# Insert null to mysql C# through stringBuilder

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, stringbuilder

When I run the following code, null does not get stored in the database and instead I get an empty string. is there a way around it?

```
    string ConnectionString = "server=localhost; password = p@ss1234; user = root; database=DB ";
        StringBuilder sCommand = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO mytable (Name) VALUES ");
        string A = null;
        using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            List<string> Rows = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                Rows.Add(string.Format("('{0}')", A));
            }
            sCommand.Append(string.Join(",", Rows));
            sCommand.Append(";");
            mConnection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(sCommand.ToString(), mConnection))
            {
                myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: please don't do this - use a parameterized query! you are asking for sql injection attacks!

Comment: you also might consider using a bulk insert operation if your mysql library supports it.

Comment: your string builder is not doing anything productive either.

Comment: I though using StringBuilder will make it faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
string.Format("('{0}')", A));
```

with this:

```
A == null ? "(null)" : string.Format("('{0}')", A));
```

Update:

Use a formatter:

```
string.Format(new SqlFormatter(), "({0}, {1})", null, A);
```

Where the formatter:

```
public class SqlFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        return arg == null ? "null" : string.Format("'{0}'", arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, but not exactly the way I wanted it. because if I have another string like   Rows.Add(string.Format("('{0}', '{1}')", "(null)", "Mark"));